# Display the most frequent values of a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to answer:

> Figure out the two most frequent job id’s in the job_history table. Use a query to output these two job id’s. Then use the results from that query to look in the Employees table to output the job_id, and average salary for those two job id’s found most frequently in the job_history table.

My solution (it doesn't display the most frequent):

```
SELECT employees.job_id, AVG(employees.salary)
FROM HR.employees,
     HR.job_history
WHERE employees.job_id = job_history.job_id
GROUP BY employees.job_id 
HAVING COUNT (job_history.job_id) >= all(
    SELECT COUNT(job_id)
    FROM hr.job_history
    GROUP BY job_id);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps `FETCH FIRST`?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Answer (score 2):

> Figure out the two most frequent job id’s in the job_history table. Use a query to output these two job id’s.

You do not need to use the `employees` table for this part of the question. You just need to use the `job_history` table and find the rows with the highest 2 frequencies:

```sql
SELECT job_id
FROM   HR.job_history
GROUP BY job_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY;
```

*Note: the `FETCH` syntax is available from Oracle 12.*

> Then use the results from that query to look in the `Employees` table to output the `job_id`, and average salary for those two `job_id`'s found most frequently in the `job_history` table.

You then need to filter the `Employees` table using the result from the previous query and find the average salary for those `job_id`s.

Since this looks like a homework question then I'll leave that part to you.